# Retrieving and using Permissions from a Service Provider in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using OIDC Authentication with WSO2 IS (5.7.0) in an Angular Application, and passing the OAuth2 Access Token (JWT) through to the backend REST APIs for Authentication (Identity Propagation) and Authorization.

I have configured the Service Provider in WSO2 so that the Roles assigned to a User are included in the Groups Claim (`groups`) in the Access Token (via the `oidc` Scope), but I'm not sure how I can determine which Permissions the User has inherited from those Roles so that I can apply some coarse-grained Authorization (RBAC) logic within my Angular App / REST APIs. Specifically, I am interested in custom Permissions added to the Service Provider.

I don't particularly want to use WSO2 IS as an XACML PDP for this coarse-grained Authorization at the boundary, but am considering using it for more fine-grained Authorization (ABAC) nearer to data access / manipulation - where we want to take attributes of the data into account. However, I'm not even sure if these Permissions can be used in XACML policies as they are not direct attributes of a User, which is the same reason they are not returned as Claims in an OAuth2 Access Token.

Is there a way to include the inherited Permissions as Claims in the OAuth2 Access Token?

Alternatively, is there a separate WSO2 IS Endpoint I can call with the Access Token to retrieve a list of Permissions - possibly even as Claims returned in a separate Token (JWT)?

From reading the documentation and searching online, there appears to be a complete disconnect between OAuth2 (Scopes/Claims) and RBAC (Roles/Permissions) in WSO2 IS. There's detail on how to Configure Users, Roles and Permissions (RBAC) in WSO2 IS, but nothing on how to then access and use that data to enforce Authorization.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with an extension.

Check https://github.com/wso2-incubator/samples-is/tree/master/custom-permission-claim-handler out.

I guess this is exactly what you are looking for.